# WCF - Binary Encoding over HTTP throwing client and service binding mismatch exception

Tags: c#, wcf

The exception:

> Content Type application/soap+msbin1
>   was not supported by service
>   http://localhost:1500/MyService.svc. 
>   The client and service bindings may be
>   mismatched.

The client configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>

    <customBinding>
        <binding name="NetHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
          <binaryMessageEncoding />
          <httpTransport allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536"
                         maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                         transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>

    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:1500/MyService.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetHttpBinding"
        contract="APP.BLL.IMyServiceContract" name="MyServiceEndpoint" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The server configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="NetHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
          <binaryMessageEncoding />
          <httpTransport allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536"
                         maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                         transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="MyAppService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetHttpBinding"
                  contract="APP.BLL.IMyServiceContract">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Is the service hosted within IIS or other hosting application?

Comment: I've been hosting it inside Visual Studio for now. The built-in webserver (I can never remember its name). I'll be deploying it to IIS when finished.

Comment: I had this same issue if the server [endpoint **Contract**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.serviceendpoint.contract.aspx) does not match the actual contract used by the endpoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use **binaryMessageEncoding** and **HTTP** without **customBindings**.  You can use **textMessageEncoding** or **mtomMessageEncoding** out of the box.

See this blog post for [reference on using **customBindings** with HTTP transport](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/02/22/WCF-Enable-Binary-Encoding-Over-Http.aspx).

```xml
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="basicHttpBinaryBinding">
        <binaryMessageEncoding />             
        <httpTransport />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: That contradicts what I've been reading on some sites: http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/02/22/WCF-Enable-Binary-Encoding-Over-Http.aspx
Do you have an article that talks about this?

Comment: HTTP is a text based protocol.  MTOM was specifically designed to add binary attachments (the old DIME protocol) to HTTP.  The binary encoder requires a binary stream not a text stream.

Comment: @mbursill - I updated the answer to reflect tested capabilities. You can get `application/soap+msbin1` content type using a `customBinding` configuration. [Jeff Barnes posting](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/02/22/WCF-Enable-Binary-Encoding-Over-Http.aspx) is accurate.